# Spring security. How salt-source works?

Tags: hash, spring-security, passwords, md5, salt

So, I new with Spring Security. I'm using password hashing with salt.In security xml file, it looks like:

```
<beans:bean id="saltSource" class="bla.bla.MyOwnSalt" scope="singleton" />
<password-encoder hash="md5" >
<salt-source ref="saltSource" />
```

MyOwnSalt implements SaltSource.

So passwords hash creating with salt.
Sometimes I need to create users and their passwords directly in database.
The main question is: How can I create a hash using only MD5 calculator, if I have password and salt?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create hash from "passwordsalt". Spring password-encoder with salt-source works like: PasswordEncoder.encode("password{salt}");
So, the problem was with missed{ }
All I had to - is to look at the PasswordEncoder source code.